# Как получить сразу несколько элементов массива?

Tags: javascript, массивы

Предположим есть массив:

`var mrArray = [1, 2, "three"];`

Получить элемент массива можно с помощью:

`array[0]`

Как получить сразу несколько элементов массива (выборочно) через запятую, например
`array[1]` и `array[2]`, только одним выражением?

Comment: Вам нужно создать новый массив на основе старого, который будет включать только определенные строки? Или вам нужно просто получить текстовую строку? Если строку, то вызываемые элементы будут идти в диапазоне каком-то или беспорядочно? А так вот: `arr.slice(1,3).join(',')`

Comment: @lampa 1)Мне нужно просто получить строку 2) Если бы я хотел создать новый массив на основе старого, я должен был бы использовать arr.push, верно? 3) Не совсем понял, я представлял себе это так, что я указываю индексы элементов, и получаю строку, где они перечислены через запятую, в том порядке, в котором я указал их индексы. 4) Клево, я правильно понял что в вашем примере мы удалили из массива три элемента, начиная со второго, и объединили оставшиеся в строку?

Comment: по сути я создал новый массив на основе старого, но указал диапазон значений, которые должны быть в новом массиве. И да, объединил их в строку.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^_^

Answer (score 3):

Самое простое - это объявить переменную, которая инициализирована из элементов другого массива, которые вам нужны.

Например,

```
var mrArray = [1, 2, "three"];
var msArray = [mrArray[1], mrArray[2]];
```

Если вам нужно выбрать некоторые элементы массива в соответствии с некоторым условием, то вы можете воспользоваться методом `filter`.

Например

```
var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1];

var filterResult = numbers.filter(function(item, index, array){
    return (item > 2);
});

alert(filterResult); //[3,4,5,4,3]
```

Для вызываемой функции достаточно указать один параметр

```
var filterResult = numbers.filter(function(item){
    return (item > 2);
});
```

Этот метод возвращает массив из выбранных элементов.

В любом случае вы можете воспользоваться обычным циклом. например,

```
var a = ["One", 2, "Three", 4, "Five", 6, "Seven", 8, "Nine", 10];
var b = [];
var c = [];

for (var i in a) {
    typeof a[i] == "string" ? b.push(a[i]) : c.push(a[i]);
}

alert(b); // ["One", "Three", "Five", "Seven", "Nine"];
alert(c); // [2, 4, 6, 8, 10];
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, очень интересный первый способ, для второго еще кое-что мне надо доизучить, спасибо!

Comment: @MaximVelichkin Я таким образом вместе с вами изучу JavaScript.:)

Answer (score 3):

Можно для массивов метод добавить:

```
Array.prototype.multiget = function(){
    var args = Array.apply(null, arguments);
    var result = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < args.length; i++){
        result.push(this[args[i]]);
    }       

    return result;
}
```

Потом вызывать так:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

console.log(arr.multiget(5,2,0)); // выведет массив [6, 3, 1]
console.log(arr.multiget(5,2,0).join(",")); // выведет строку "6,3,1"
```

Comment: Очень интересно, кое-что из этого я еще не изучал, буду разбираться, большое спасибо!

Comment: @MaximVelichkin будут ещё вопросы, спрашивайте )